# Android scrollview hide gradient shadow

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` nested in a `LinearLayout`. Android have this gradient shadow from the top of the `ScrollView` that i want do disable.

I know that you can disable the shadow under the title if you change the theme with `windowContentOverlay`, do anyone know of a similar solution for the `ScrollView`?

things i have already tried: `fadingEdge`, `overScrollmode`, `windowContentOverlay`.

As seen in the picture below, the shadow is where the `ScrollView` start, above the `ScrollView` is a `TextView`.

[image: Gradiend shadow]

Comment: Does tge shadow appear when you scroll up? Or is it the default mode? It should have worked with fadibgEdge...

Comment: its in default mode, it always shows even if i scroll down

Comment: got it solved, looked through the code with new eyes (non sleepy ones) and it was a style that messed it up (gonna smack the one who wrote the code ;) ) thanks anyway :)

Comment: Good to hear :) i was wondering how this was possible :D